# Last day of the leap year, week 53 or 1?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a script that process raw CSV data and generate report grouped by week of the year.
Which looks something like this:

```
//timezone is set to Europe/London
$date = new DateTime($raw['order_date']); // example: 12/31/2012

$key = $date->format('Y W'); // 2012 01

$array[$key][] = $raw['product_id'];
```

Everything was working fine until I tried to parse data generated over new year eve, for some reason system believes that 31 December 2012 is week number 1 of year 2012. 
I'm not sure is it bug or a feature, but produced reports are definitely wrong.

What is a correct way of passing this issue and keeping data grouped by weeks?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week - it's correct - look here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$key = $date->format('o W');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the week is defined Thursday, meaning if the Thursday falls in 2013, then it's counted as being a week of that year.

Answer (score 0):

```
$w=(int)date('W');

$m=(int)date('n');

$w=$w==1?($m==12?53:1):($w>=51?($m==1?0:$w):$w);

$year = date('Y');

if($w==53)

{

$year=$year+1;

}
```

past year i am getting all d records properly but in 2016 april first select than I got april 2015 report show any thing missing or its leap year problem